# Java sql select from db in batches

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a postgres table which contains millions of entries and I wish to query it in batches of `10.000`. That means that I have to send a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
```

and instead of getting the millions of entries I wanna get 10.000, then store their ids in an array, do something with the ids and continue reading the next batch of 10.000. Is there any way to do it this in Java?

So far I am using a prepared statement like so:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
String sql = "SELECT id FROM my_table ";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(handleDatabaseSyntax(sql));
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
  ids.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

I saw that the `PreparedStatement` has some aid for it but I am not sure how to use it. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setFetchSize`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example) with a value different from 0 so that the JDBC driver doesn't fetch the whole result set at once.

Then loop similar to how you did it:

```java
statement.setFetchSize(200);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
int counter = 0;
while (rs.next())
{
    ids.add(rs.getString(1));
    if (++counter % 10000 == 0)
    {
        /* do something with "ids" */
        ids.removeAll();
    }
}
/* do something with the remaining "ids" */
```